# Processing only n items at a time concurrently using Task Parallel Library

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

This is all happening in a windows service.

I have a `Queue<T>` (actually a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`) holding items waiting to be processed. But, I don't want to process only one at a time, I want to process n items concurrently, where n is a configurable integer.

How do I go about doing this using the Task Parallel Library?

I know that TPL will partition collections on behalf of the developer for concurrent processing, but not sure if that's the feature that I'm after. I'm new to multithreading and TPL.

Answer (score 4):

Use `BlockingCollection<T>` instead of `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, then you can start any number of consumer threads and use `Take` method of the `BlockingCollection`. if the collection is empty, the `Take` method will automatically block in the caller thread waiting for items to be added, otherwise the threads will consume all the queue items in parallel. However as your question mentioned out the use of TPL  it turns out that `Parallel.ForEach` have some issues when using with `BlockingCollection` check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) post for more details. so you have to manage creation of your consumer threads your self. `new Thread(/*consumer method*/)` or `new Task()`...

Comment: The BlockingCollection defeats the purpose of the queue. I can't remove an item from a blocking collection while it's being iterated over.

Comment: No you can by using its [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) instead. like, `foreach (Item item in _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())` it will also block there waiting for items to be added if the collection is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one idea that involves creating an extension method for `TaskFactory`.

```
public static class TaskFactoryExtension
{
    public static Task StartNew(this TaskFactory target, Action action, int parallelism)
    {
        var tasks = new Task[parallelism];
        for (int i = 0; i < parallelism; i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = target.StartNew(action);
        }
        return target.StartNew(() => Task.WaitAll(tasks));
    }
}
```

Then your calling code would look like the following.

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> queue = GetQueue();
int n = GetDegreeOfParallelism();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () =>
  {
    T item;
    while (queue.TryDequeue(out item))
    {
      ProcessItem(item);
    }
  }, n);
task.Wait(); // Optionally wait for everything to finish.
```

Here is another idea using `Parallel.ForEach`. The problem with this approach is that your degrees of parallelism might not necessarily be honored. You are only indicating the maximum amount allowed and not the absolute amount.

```
ConcurrentQueue<T> queue = GetQueue();
int n = GetDegreeOfParallelism();
Parallel.ForEach(queue, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = n },
  (item) =>
  {
    ProcessItem(item);    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend using a `BlockingCollection` instead of directly using a `ConcurrentQueue`.

Here's an example:

```
public class QueuingRequestProcessor
{
  private BlockingCollection<MyRequestType> queue;

  public void QueuingRequestProcessor(int maxConcurrent)
  {
    this.queue = new BlockingCollection<MyRequestType>(maxConcurrent);

    Task[] consumers = new Task[maxConcurrent];

    for (int i = 0; i < maxConcurrent; i++)
    {
      consumers[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        // Will wait when queue is empty, until CompleteAdding() is called
        foreach (var request in this.queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
          Process(request);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  public void Add(MyRequest request)
  {
    this.queue.Add(request);
  }

  public void Stop()
  {
    this.queue.CompleteAdding();
  }

  private void Process(MyRequestType request)
  {
    // Do your processing here
  }
}
```

Note that `maxConcurrent` in the constructor defines how many requests will be processed concurrently.